# Rails - How to store each update of an item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I'm not sure how to do this in rails (maybe its a common topic but I'm not even sure if the title is correct)

I have a product table with this fields

- Name
- Quantity
- Price
- Size

and the columns that rails provide (id, created_at, updated_at)

This table is going to be updated periodically (lets say each day or so) but I want to save the QUANTITY that is being ADDED, and the date/time of the actualization (UPDATE).

I'm not sure if it's a design problem or something else.

Is there a way rails can handle this?

Thanks in advance

Javier QQ.

Comment: Do you want to store quantity added for each time you update it? Or just the most recent one?

Comment: yes, lets say I have 5 items of the first product an after an hour I add 10 items and the next day 20. I want to store each quantity that's being added and also the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for... but you can try the [papertrail Gem](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail). It stores each update of your model and you can easily step backwards or forwards in time through them to inspect your model and what fields changed, so it sounds like it'd be pretty ideal for what you have in mind.

Comment: It looks like a "version control" of an item is it?. I want to save each update because then I'm going to show a graphic that shows each day that item was updated. It seems that its what I'm looking but I was wondering if you have used in a similar case :)

Comment: I've search more and yes its helpful https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Versioning. Many thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

Given what you've said in your comments, why don't you just make a new table, say a "Stock" table. Each stock has two fields (in addition to the default created_at and updated_at): quantity and item_id.

Whenever you want to update an item with a new quantity, in the update method (or stock method, whatever it is) you do:

```
Stock.create(:item_id => @item.id, :quantity => params[:quantity])
```

This also ensures that you know when stock was added, because Rails will automatically keep track of when this Stock was made.

Comment: I actually thought that, create another table that saves it as you mention, but maybe rails have some "special" method that I don't know :)

Comment: And to see how many items you have in stock you can simply use a function like `Stock.sum( :quantitiy, conditions: ['item_id = ?', myItem.id])`

Comment: @JavierQQ23 Nope. No special methods